# Rails 5 not using form_for method "patch", defaulting to "get"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to update a user's info and I'm using form_for.  When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit, my error is that it cannot find a route for [GET]"/users/1/edit".  Why is Rails using the GET html verb?

My users_controller, routes and view:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

--------

resource :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

    Prefix Verb  URI Pattern           Controller#Action
     users POST  /users(.:format)      users#create
 new_users GET   /users/new(.:format)  users#new
edit_users GET   /users/edit(.:format) users#edit
           PATCH /users(.:format)      users#update
           PUT   /users(.:format)      users#update
--------

<%= form_for(@user, url: edit_users_path(@user), html: {method: "patch"}) do |f| %>
  Username: <%= f.text_field :username %><br>
  Email:    <%= f.text_field :email %><br>
  Password: <%= f.text_field :password %><br>
            <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `routes.rb`, change `resource` to `resources`:

```
    resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

Right now, your route doesn't accept any params. Your path goes to `/users/edit`, instead of `/users/:id/edit`.

```
     Prefix Verb   URI       Pattern           Controller#Action
     edit_users    GET   /users/edit(.:format)    users#edit
```